# Did Green Lantern ever have a 'Robin'

Tags: dc, green-lantern

It seems like it was fairly common for Comic heroes to begin teaming up with kids in their crime fighting.  Batman had Robin, Captain America had Bucky, Green Arrow had Speedy, Aquaman had Aqualad, etc.

Did any of the Green Lanterns ever have something like this?

Comment: HA! He would say otherwise, but does Guy Gardner count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Green Lantern had several "sidekicks" including [Doiby Dickles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doiby_Dickles)

[image: Doiby Dickles]

[Streak the Wonder Dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Green_Lantern_supporting_characters)

[image]

[Kyro](http://superfriends.wikia.com/wiki/Kyro)

[image: Kyro]

and [Pie Face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Kalmaku) (AKA Thomas Kalmaku)

[image: PieFace]

You can also find a pretty comprehensive list of his supporting characters [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Green_Lantern_supporting_characters)

Comment: Most of those are, as you said, supporting characters.  The question was about sidekick heroes (Robin, Speedy, etc).

Comment: Pieface was definitely more of a sidekick. He saved Hal's life on numerous occasions...

Comment: Great fish-hooks!

Answer (score 2):

Itty.

[image]

From the DC Wikia:

> "Itty" was one of the Ayries. In his youth, he befriended Hal Jordan
>   and joined him on many adventures, until he was apparently killed. He
>   actually transformed into adulthood, from a small starfish to a huge
>   gas-like humanoid. He fled back to space, where he met a mate in
>   Lasma. The two of them were the last survivors of their race, and were
>   being hunted by the Laroo. With Hal's help, they defeated them.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the current set of heroes who use the name 'Green Lantern' the answer is "Nope, not really."  Ever since Hal Jordan first took the name, Green Lantern never had a teenaged superhero sidekick.  Typically, the role they can be play in stories (exposition-requiring trainee, hostage, *machina* for the *deus*, etc) can be filled by another member of the Green Lantern corps, often a trainee.

Once the Green Lantern Corps expanded to include 2 for each space sector, this became even easier to write in, as it was no longer rare for two Green Lanterns to meet while 'on the job'.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I've never read Alan Scott.  Figured he might have had something.

Comment: He had several teenaged sidekicks including Kyro and Pieface...

Comment: @Richard: Ah, serves me right for discounting the character who hasn't been relevant for 30 years :)

Comment: @Jeff - As I said, this is why I hate comic-book questions :-) You can always find some weird one-part from the 1940s that proves you wrong.

Answer (score -1):

There was also briefly a [Kid Lantern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Green_Lanterns#Kid_Lantern).

Comment: "Kid Lantern" was Wally West (AKA Kid Flash) who temporarily wore a power ring generated by Hal Jordan. He certainly wasn't a true sidekick.